# How do I properly setup If/Else statements to open a program under conditions with AutoHotkey?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, autohotkey

What I need using AutoHotkey (v1) is to open a single instance of a program on my desktop computer if it is not already running...
If it is already running and minimized, restore it...
If it is running and active, to do nothing?

So far under different attempted layouts I have been able to get close with it opening my program if not open and only running a single instance if it is already runnning. I just can't reliably get it to unminimize if it is already minimized.

```
Window Title, Class and Process - per Window Spy...
- Colorpicker
- ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
- ahk_exe Colorpicker.exe
```

One of my attempts...

```
if WinExist("ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1"){     ; if the window exists

    if WinActive("ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1") 
;       WinRestore, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
        WinActivate
    else{
        WinActivate ; otherwise make it the active window
    }
}else
    run, C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Colorpicker\Colorpicker.exe
return
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this using...

```
ifWinNotExist, [Program name]
  Run, [Path to exe]
  
ifWinActive, [Program name]
  return

Else
ifWinNotActive, [Program name]
WinActivate , [Program name]
```